# Retrieve vertices from CGAL's Delaunay Constrained Triangulation

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I have a list of 2D points, which describe a simple polygon. I compute the Delaunay constrained thanks to CGAL.

```
    Polygon_2 polygon;
    //Create a polygon from a vector
    for(int j=0; j < (*itVectorPoint2D).size(); j++) {
        polygon.push_back(Point((*itVectorPoint2D)[j].x,(*itVectorPoint2D)[j].y));
    }

    //Insert the polygon into a constrained triangulation
    CDT cdt;
    insert_polygon(cdt,polygon);
    //Mark facets that are inside the domain bounded by the polygon
    mark_domains(cdt);

    for (CDT::Finite_faces_iterator fit=cdt.finite_faces_begin(); fit!=cdt.finite_faces_end();++fit)
    {
        if (fit->info().in_domain()) {
            std::cout << (*(fit->vertex(0))) << ";" << (*(fit->vertex(1))) << ";" << (*(fit->vertex(2))) << std::endl;
        }

    }
```

My problem is that I want to retrieve every triangle with the triplet of indices from the initial vector.For example, for a square define by **0**:(0,0) **1**:(1,0) **2**:(1,1) and **3**:(0,1), I want to retrieve (**0**, **1**, **2**) and (**0**, **2**, **3**). I could retrieve the coordinates of the current vertex and compare them to every point in the vector, but it's *ugly* I think (and inefficient, possible source of problem ?).

Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: do you need the indices to match the insertion order or would you be OK if the indices matches the order of the vertices in the triangulation?

Comment: @sloriot : i'd like to retrieve _j_ I use in the first loop, so yes the input order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works fine with CGAL 4.2. Note that with CGAL 4.3 there will be a dedicated function doing the job in a more integrated way like it is done [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_37.11.2) for the `Delaunay_triangulation_2` class.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Spatial_sort_traits_adapter_2.h>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;

typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K>           Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb>              TDS;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag                               Itag;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, TDS, Itag> CDT;
typedef CDT::Point          Point;
typedef CGAL::Spatial_sort_traits_adapter_2<K,Point*> Search_traits;

template <class InputIterator>
void insert_with_info(CDT& cdt, InputIterator first,InputIterator last)
{
  std::vector<std::ptrdiff_t> indices;
  std::vector<Point> points;
  std::ptrdiff_t index=0;

  for (InputIterator it=first;it!=last;++it){
    points.push_back( *it);
    indices.push_back(index++);
  }

  CGAL::spatial_sort(indices.begin(),indices.end(),Search_traits(&(points[0]),cdt.geom_traits()));

  CDT::Vertex_handle v_hint;
  CDT::Face_handle hint;
  for (typename std::vector<std::ptrdiff_t>::const_iterator
    it = indices.begin(), end = indices.end();
    it != end; ++it){
    v_hint = cdt.insert(points[*it], hint);
    if (v_hint!=CDT::Vertex_handle()){
      v_hint->info()=*it;
      hint=v_hint->face();
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector< Point > points;
  points.push_back( Point(0,0) );
  points.push_back( Point(1,0) );
  points.push_back( Point(0,1) );
  points.push_back( Point(14,4) );
  points.push_back( Point(2,2) );
  points.push_back( Point(-4,0) );


  CDT cdt;
  insert_with_info(cdt, points.begin(), points.end());

  CGAL_assertion( cdt.number_of_vertices() == 6 );

  // check that the info was correctly set.
  CDT::Finite_vertices_iterator vit;
  for (vit = cdt.finite_vertices_begin(); vit != cdt.finite_vertices_end(); ++vit)
    if( points[ vit->info() ] != vit->point() ){
      std::cerr << "Error different info" << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If I understand well, vit->info() returns j. Since I am a beginner with CGAL, I don't understand the line :

CGAL::spatial_sort(indices.begin(),indices.end(),Search_traits(&(points[0]),cdt.geom_traits()));

What is it for ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: In order to speed up the insertion of points in the triangulation, points are sorted along an Hilbert curve that guarantee that two consecutive points are not far from each other. The sort is done on the indices.

Comment: This is a late question. But, I don't see a sample on how to do this intuitively like for the unconstrained Delaunay Triangulation. Is there a way?

Comment: See [this function](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__Delaunay__triangulation__2.html#a39734a9d8817729037b36c2b60641fbc)